# Why does this line of script crash apache?

Tags: php, syntax-error

Here's the branch of code I've isolated...

```
if ( !is_search() 
    && (get_option('option1') 
        && !(is_page() 
            || get_option('option2') 
                || get_option('option3') 
                    || in_category('excludeme', $post )
            )
        )
    )
```

I've inserted...

```
<?php print "Hi, Mom!\n"; exit; ?>
```

above and below this line to isolate the cause of the crash

Comment: How do you know it's this line?

Comment: What error message are you getting? What are the symptoms?

Comment: I don't know why it would crash apache, but it sure crashed my internal on the fly-parser. It can't stand scolling.

Comment: I've inserted <?php print "Hi, Mom!\n"; exit; ?> above and below this line to isolate the cause of the crash.

Comment: The original has one fewer closing bracket than the broken down one.

Comment: I think its a typo on my part. Let me check the code though.

Comment: Are you sure it's crashing your server? Do you have to reboot the server every time you execute this code?

Comment: @BoltClock: No reboot required. its just saying, "Apache HTTP Server has stopped working > Close the program" Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version: 2.2.14.0
  Application Timestamp: 4aeb9704
  Fault Module Name: php5ts.dll

Comment: It sounds like a bug in PHP (php5ts.dll is the core DLL), or perhaps in an extension. It would help if you could isolate the problem to one of those functions you use (just call them independently one by one) and tell us what they are.

Comment: It looks like when one of my option values is empty its causing the error. When a fill in a value for that option, no error. I'm testing for && $option !=='' and I need to change it to if(isset($option))

Comment: Check the apaches (and PHP's) error logs!

Comment: If `$option` is not set, `$option!==''` is TRUE, while `isset($option)` is FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try breaking out your code into chunks to further isolate the problem:
This is obviously a WordPress template, and even though you may think the problem is not in the core WordPress code, you may need to put debugging output inside the core functions to find out exactly where the problem is happening.  In other words, you need to go inside these functions calls to find out what is causing the problem - you might find a solution to your problem at that point.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

echo PHP_EOL . 'is_search' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump( is_search() );

echo PHP_EOL . 'get option 1' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump( get_option('option1') );

echo PHP_EOL . 'is_page' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump( is_page() );

echo PHP_EOL . 'get option 2' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump( get_option('option2') );

echo PHP_EOL . 'get option 3' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump( get_option('option3') );

echo PHP_EOL . 'in category' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump( in_category('excludeme', $post ) );
```